# Laravel Remembering redirect location over multiple steps in login process

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, redirect, exception

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and the default authentication approach.

I have a scenario where an unknown user may start a registration process (started with 1 POSTed form).  The output of that form shows a button (to modal login) allowing the person to login (if they have an account).

I want to be able to let them login via that form and stay on the current page if they login successfully (refreshing it with authenticated user information) or get redirected back to that same page with the modal up and showing the "bad credentials" message in the modal.

If I cannot redirect back to the initial page with the open modal, I'd be ok with showing the normal login screen with error message(s) but I would then want to remember the original redirection target which, possibly, is now once removed.

The first part of this process was working but seems to have partially broken with the change to one of the newer versions of Laravel (when the error message UI changed).  Right now, a user can launch the modal and supply credentials.

When the credentials are correct, the user is successfully authenticated (as session state for other browser tabs allows me to go through auth areas of the site) but a MethodNotAllowedHttpException is presented instead of taking the user back to the form where the login was initiated.

I believe the exception is being generated because the redirection back to the page where login was initiated was originally due to a POST and redirections are GETs.

How do I work around this or set it up so that it works as desired?

I'm willing to provide any specific code that would help to troubleshoot.

`php artisan route:list` does show all the routes I expect I need for this.

Answer (score 0):

After searching around here, I found a related post and decided that I needed to refactor the code so that one form does the POST and then it redirects to a GET URL.  That way, the redirection from a failed login works without throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to look at `return redirect()->intended()`.

Look more into this: https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Routing/Redirector.html#method_intended

Comment: That is what was being used.  It doesn't address redirection back to a page that was the output of a POST.